# Assigning objects to variables

Tags: c#

I have a simple program with with an employee class and i have 2 objects in this class `lynda` and `alex`, I have  also created a method called `CalculateTotalPay()` which prints the total pay to the console after a simple addition of the `salary` and `bonus`. Right now the for the print to console I have `Console.WriteLine("Total  Pay = " + totalPay);` but I want to make it into
`Console.WriteLine("Total  Pay for " + employeeName " = " + totalPay);` but I dont want to repeatedly assing new employees to new variables, what would be the best way to do this ?

Here is the Code

```
class Employee
{
    public double salary;
    public double bonus;
    public string employeeName;

    public void CalculateTotalPay()
    {
        double totalPay = salary + bonus;
        Console.WriteLine("Total  Pay = " + totalPay);
    }
}
```

---

```
static void Main()
{
    Employee alex = new Employee();
    Employee lynda = new Employee();

    alex.salary = 900000;
    alex.bonus = 20000;
    alex.CalculateTotalPay();

    lynda.salary = 100000;
    lynda.bonus = 20000;
    lynda.CalculateTotalPay();
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to assign a variable, where do you think the information should come from? You know you can reuse the same variable again, right?

Comment: If you want different employee's you've got to assign them one way or another. thats inevitable. You could automize it a bit, for instance, reading and writing the object data to a file or database.

Comment: get the name from constructor. because you assign any name to objects. currently they are just variable names.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I want to create a variable is in a way that I only have to put the variable once in the print command however the only way I have learnt is to create a variable for each object which would be too time consuming

Comment: Well do you have an external list of all employee information?

Comment: @Rinecamo No, I have just created this program to help consolidate what i have learnt in c# it just has the 2 objects lynda and alex

Comment: @NafisRahman I don't really understand what exactly your problem is. If you just want to print it out and don't need the objects you can hardcode it anyway `Console.WriteLine("Total Pay for {0} = {1}", "alex", 900000, 20000)`. If not in a database or an external file, you have to define the information inside the code. There's no way to avoid this.

Comment: @Rinecamo I declared the objects once already, I want to be able print the name of the employee without having to type his/ her name up again and again which would be redundant and tedious

Comment: @NafisRahman So you basically want the name of the variable to be used? That's impossible, you have to define the names seperately.

Answer (score 2):

First, your class should look like this:

```
class Employee
{
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public double Bonus { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Employee(String name, double salary, double bonus)
    {
        Salary = salary;
        Bonus = bonus;
        Name = name;
    }

    public void CalculateTotalPay()
    {
        double totalPay = Salary + Bonus;
        Console.WriteLine("Total  Pay for {0} = {1}", Name, totalPay);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply use the constructor:

```
Employee alex = new Employee("alex", 900000, 20000);
Employee lynda = new Employee("lynda", 100000, 20000);
```

Edit: Apparently your problem is a bit different.
If you have no external source of information you have to define all employees inside the code. I would recommend this way:

```
List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee("alex", 900000, 20000),
    new Employee("lynda", 100000, 20000)
};

foreach (var employee in Employees) {
        employee.CalculateTotalPay();
}
```

For the sake of readability, do it this way and don't start to make like 3 seperate arrays for bonuses, salaries and names.

Comment: you still need a new object whenever calling `Employee` constructor.

Comment: Can we make Name, Salary, Bonus properties as private set? They should not be changed from outside of class. For sure the name should not be changed from outside of class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<Employee> workers = new List<Employee>();`.
Add new Employee is easy - `workers.Add( new Employee {salary = 10, bonus = 100});`.
And finally you can interate over this collection:

```
foreach (var item in workers)
{
    //TODO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were looking for below solution.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee("Alex", 900000, 20000),
            new Employee("Lynda", 100000, 20000)
        };

        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            employee.CalculatePay();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    private readonly double _salary;
    private readonly double _bonus;
    private readonly string _name;

    public double Salary { get { return _salary; } }
    public double Bonus { get { return _bonus; } }
    public string Name { get { return _name; } }

    public Employee(string name, double salary, double bonus)
    {
        _name = name;
        _salary = salary;
        _bonus = bonus;
    }

    public void CalculatePay()
    {
        double totalPay = Salary + Bonus;
        Console.WriteLine("Total Pay for Employee {0} = {1}", Name, totalPay);
    }
}
```